Why is $\int_0^1{df(tx_1,\dots, tx_n)\over dt}=\int_0^1\sum_{i=1}^n{\partial f\over\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot x_i\;dt$?
For context: Milnor's Morse theory page 6, Lemma 2.1:

$V$ is a convex neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

also,

$f,g \in C^\infty \left( V \rightarrow \mathbb R^n\right)$

where

$f(0) = 0$ and $g_i (0) = {\partial f \over \partial x_i}(0)$.

His actual lemma 2.1 isn't germane to this discussion, but I don't understand this beginning step of his proof.
$$ f(x_1, \dots , x_n) = \int\limits_0^1{df(tx_1,\dots, tx_n)\over dt}=\int\limits_0^1\sum_{i=1}^n\limits{\partial f\over\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot x_i\;dt$$
The first two parts of the equality make sense to me. I don't understand how they are equal to the third part of the equality. I can't tell whether this is just me forgetting a really easy property from vector or multivariable calculus or if this is some deeper property that comes from, say, the consequences of the differential being defined on a convex neighborhood.
A proof or a reference would be appreciated.

Please use MathJax for the title, or if it is too long, simply write an overview of the problem: e.g. Integral problem. or something.

Whoops! I forgot to add the dollar signs. Fixed.

Is this not just chain rule?

Use the chain rule.
Let $h(t)=f(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)$, then
$$\frac{dh}{dt}(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\,\cdot\,\frac{\partial (tx_i)}{\partial t}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\,\cdot\,x_i.$$
So the last equality is proven.

In your middle term:
Why is it $\partial f \over \partial x_i$ instead of $\partial f \over \partial ((t x_i)$

I don't agree that it's notation for the same thing. Take  ${d\over d tx}\sin (tx) \cdot {d \over dt} tx = x \cos (tx)$. Whereas ${d\over d x}\sin (tx) \cdot {d \over dt} tx =  tx \cos (tx)$. The property only holds by the fact that our lower bound of the integral is $0$ and that we evaluate the upper bound at $t=1$. We can apply Stone-Weierstrass theorem to easily prove that these terms are equal up to our integral, but it does not hold in the general case.
